# simulate cpu usage in mono for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I need to write an application in mono for android(Android+c#.net) to simulate steady cpu usage for certain duration(eg:30%,50%,70%) for 2 sec.
I refered below link
[Simulate steady CPU load and spikes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514544/simulate-steady-cpu-load-and-spikes) 
here i can able to steady the system cpu but the same operation not able to do in Android os.
Any help can be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample project which seems to work fine on my Samsung Galaxy S2 and in the Emulator.

https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MonoDroid.CPULoader

It just uses the resources you linked to.

Comment: Hi thanks for your great help. How did u conform the application hogging by the given load? please let me knw

Comment: I used cool tool to monitor the cpu. You can also check the CPU load through adb, but it is not as precise because it does not update as often as cool tool does.