# Running a .NET app slower

Tags: .net, virtualization

I'd like to test my programs running on older machines. How can you run a .NET app as though you were on a slower processor? eg: run as if on a 400 mHz processor -- the .NET 2.0 minimum requirement. (I know RAM, hard drive speed, etc. would effect my running time also, but I have to start somewhere.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Simulate Lower CPU Processor Machines For Browser Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928534/how-to-simulate-lower-cpu-processor-machines-for-browser-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [how-to-simulate-lower-cpu-processor-machines-for-browser-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928534/how-to-simulate-lower-cpu-processor-machines-for-browser-testing) - which should provide the answer - looks pretty straightforward!